# function use variable reference

Tags: php, variables, reference, global

```
$ret = array();

$params = array(
                    "conTableArry"=>array("connection"=> parent::PDO_("geo", false),"table"=>"locations"),
                    "fields"=>array("ID", "LOCALITY_ID", "COUNTY", "LAT_", "LONG_", "ZIPCODE"),
                    "condArry"=>$condArry,
                    "LIMIT"=>2
                );
                parent::search($params, function($location) use (&$ret){
                    echo "a";
                    $params = array(
                        "conTableArry"=>array("connection"=> parent::PDO_("geo", false),"table"=>"locality"),
                        "fields"=>array("ID","NAME","PROVINCE_ID"),
                        "condArry"=>array(array("ID",$location["LOCALITY_ID"])),
                        "LIMIT"=>2
                    );
                    $_usable_ = array($location, $ret);
                    parent::search($params, function($locality) use (&$_usable_){
                        $params = array(
                            "conTableArry"=>array("connection"=> parent::PDO_("geo", false),"table"=>"provinces"),
                            "fields"=>array("ID","NAME","ABBR"),
                            "condArry"=>array(array("ID",$locality["PROVINCE_ID"])),
                            "LIMIT"=>2
                        );
                        $_usable_ = array($_usable_[0], $locality, $_usable_[1]);
                        parent::search($params, function($province) use(&$_usable_){
                            **$val = array($_usable_[0], $_usable_[1], $province);
                            echo "<br>-";
                            print_r($val);
                            echo "<br>-";
                            print_r($_usable_[0]);
                            echo "<br>-";
                            print_r($_usable_[0]);
                            echo "<br>-";
                            print_r($province);
                            echo "<br>-";
                            array_push($_usable_[2], $val);**
                        });
                    });
                });
return $ret;
```

when after pushing my $val into $_usable[2]  (should be the original ret)
My $ret still returns an empty array.
I am 100% sure that the $val is not null, and contains another array ( i tested that ).

The issue is the passing by reference i believe.

I would like to avoid using the return inside the function, so passing by reference is the way to go here.

Comment: Note * there is repetitive code in this snippet, i had to pull apart certain methods to find the error.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there is a bug,
When passing a referenced variable inside an array the array clones the value.

PHP arrays are not references like C++.

```
class obj_{
    $ret = 0;
    $set = 1;
    protected alpha() use (&$ret, &$set){
         function alpha_brava() use (&$ret, &$set){
             $ret += $set; 
        }
    }
}
```

the return should be 1.